# Restricting Query Results with CanCan

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, authorization, cancan

I want to restrict access to `report` models according to roles via CanCan. Specifically, I want `:admin` roles to manage all, `:expert` roles create, read and edit all reports ascribed to their team and delete only their own, and `user` roles to create, read, edit, and delete their own reports.

`@reports = report.pending_approval.by_team(current_user.team_id)`

Based on the following abilities, and [authorize_resource](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions#authorize_resource) in all relevant controllers, I expected the above query to **only** return reports the user has created -- but it returns all the reports for a given team. I want the query to return all "pending" reports belonging to a particular team if the `current_user` is an `:expert` and is assigned to the team in question.

Does anyone know why it returns all reports belonging to a team, regardless of whether the current_user is an expert or not? Should I modify the query to check for (`:expert`) role? To limit access to the team expert only, should I modify the query to check for team membership and role in the query or CanCan ability?

```
class Ability                                                                           
  include CanCan::Ability                                                               

  def initialize(user)                                                                  
    user ||= User.new                                                                   

    if user.role? :admin                                                                
      can :manage, :all                                                                 
    elsif user.role? :expert                                                                                      
      can :read, Report, :user_id => user.id, :submitted => false                
      can :create, Report                                                            
      can :update, Report, :user_id => user.id, :submitted => false              
      can :destroy, Report, :user_id => user.id, :submitted => false             
    else                                                                                                                             
      can :read, Report, :user_id => user.id, :submitted => false                
      can :create, Report
      can :update, Report, :user_id => user.id, :submitted => false              
      can :destroy, Report, :user_id => user.id, :submitted => false             
    end                                                                                 
  end                                                                                   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you gave has no CanCan methods in it, so it doesn't know about your restrictions.

Try using `accessible_by` to scope the relation:

```
Report.accessible_by(Ability.new(current_user)).pending_approval # ... etc
```

Comment: Also have a look at the [CanCan wiki on fetching records](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I have [authorize_resource](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions#authorize_resource) in all the relevant controllers. I was under the impression the results of the custom query, when loaded, would be vetted by CanCan.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is this for the index action? `authorize_resource` should assign `Report.accessible_by(current_ability)` to a `@reports` variable, onto which you can chain your own relation methods, e.g. `@reports = @reports.pending_approval.by_team(current_user.team_id)`.

Comment: Here is the docs straight from CanCan https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records